# pagination append doesn't work in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I have my search result I also have my paginator in the view but when I click on pages it returns `404` error.

**I've tried this:**

```
1- @include('front.partials.pagination', ['paginator' => $products])

2- {{$products->appends(Request::except(['page','_token']))->links() }}

3- {{$products->appends(request()->query())->links() }}

4- $products->appends(['brands' => $brandss]); //in contoller
```

All of them have the same result `404 Error`

**Here is my complete function:**

```
public function advancedsearch(Request $request) {
    // dd($request->all());
    $options = Specification::whereHas('subspecifications')->with(['subspecifications' => function($query){
        $query->status('Active');
    }])->get();

    $brandss = Input::has('brands') ? Input::get('brands') : [];
    $suboption = Input::has('suboptions') ? (int)Input::get('suboptions') : [];
    $min_price = Input::has('min_price') ? (int)Input::get('min_price') : null;
    $max_price = Input::has('max_price') ? (int)Input::get('max_price') : null;


    //codes
    if(!empty($request->input('brands')) && !empty($request->input('min_price')) && !empty($request->input('max_price'))){
      $products = Product::
      where('price', '>=', $min_price)
      ->where('price', '<=', $max_price)
      ->whereIn('brand_id', $brandss)
      ->paginate(12);
      $products->appends(['brands' => $brandss, 'suboptions' => $suboption, 'min_price' => $min_price, 'max_price' => $max_price]);
    }


    elseif(!empty($request->input('suboptions')) && !empty($request->input('min_price')) && !empty($request->input('max_price'))){
      $products = DB::table('products')
        ->join('product_subspecification', function ($join) {
          $suboption = Input::has('suboptions') ? Input::get('suboptions') : [];
              $join->on('products.id', '=', 'product_subspecification.product_id')
                   ->where('product_subspecification.subspecification_id', '=', $suboption);
          })
          ->where('products.price', '>=', $min_price)
          ->where('products.price', '<=', $max_price)
        ->paginate(12);
        $products->appends(['brands' => $brandss, 'suboptions' => $suboption, 'min_price' => $min_price, 'max_price' => $max_price]);
    }

    //
    elseif(!empty($request->input('brands')) && !empty($request->input('suboptions'))){
      $products = DB::table('products')
        ->whereIn('products.brand_id', $brandss)
        ->join('product_subspecification', function ($join) {
          $suboption = Input::has('suboptions') ? Input::get('suboptions') : [];
              $join->on('products.id', '=', 'product_subspecification.product_id')
                   ->where('product_subspecification.subspecification_id', '=', $suboption);
          })
        ->paginate(12);
        $products->appends(['brands' => $brandss, 'suboptions' => $suboption]);
    }

    elseif(!empty($request->input('brands')) && !empty($request->input('suboptions')) && !empty($request->input('min_price')) && !empty($request->input('max_price'))){
      $products = DB::table('products')
        ->join('product_subspecification', function ($join) {
          $suboption = Input::has('suboptions') ? Input::get('suboptions') : [];
              $join->on('products.id', '=', 'product_subspecification.product_id')
                   ->where('product_subspecification.subspecification_id', '=', $suboption);
          })
          ->where('products.price', '>=', $min_price)
          ->where('products.price', '<=', $max_price)
          ->whereIn('products.brand_id', $brandss)
        ->paginate(12);
        $products->appends(['brands' => $brandss, 'suboptions' => $suboption, 'min_price' => $min_price, 'max_price' => $max_price]);
    }
    //


    elseif(!empty($request->input('suboptions'))){
        $products = DB::table('products')
        ->join('product_subspecification', function ($join) {
          $suboption = Input::has('suboptions') ? Input::get('suboptions') : [];
              $join->on('products.id', '=', 'product_subspecification.product_id')
                   ->where('product_subspecification.subspecification_id', '=', $suboption);
          })
        ->paginate(12);
        $products->appends(['suboptions' => $suboptions]);
    }

    elseif(!empty($request->input('brands'))){
      $products = DB::table('products')
      ->whereIn('products.brand_id', $brandss)
      ->paginate(12);
      $products->appends(['brands' => $brandss]);
    }

    elseif($request->has('min_price') && $request->has('max_price')){
      $products = DB::table('products')
      ->whereBetween('price', [$min_price, $max_price])
      ->paginate(12);
      $products->appends(['min_price' => $min_price, 'max_price' => $max_price]);
    }


    return view('front.advancesearch', compact('products', 'options'));
}
```

Any idea?

................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: which laravel version you using ?

Comment: @EmtiazZahid 5.6

Comment: What about the pagination links URL? Did you checked it?

Comment: @sadaiMudiNaadhar is coming like `site.com?brands[]=1&page=2`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add some data in laravel paginate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41034351/add-some-data-in-laravel-paginate)

Comment: @WalterCejas whaaaaat?! what custom data to be merged? bro please see the code first I did publish my controller do you see any additional data except `$products = DB::....`?

Comment: What kind of URL is that ! Just try URL works manually.(In Any case)

Comment: @sadaiMudiNaadhar `site.com/advanced-search?brands[0]=2&page=2` the `page=2` is basic pagination url and `?brands[0]=2` is the part that i appened in url which supposed to let pagination works without losing the search data.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Eloquent in the first part and  query builder in the second part, and appends is an eloquent method, the collection that you receive from query builder is not the same than the one from eloquent Eloquent.. it doesnt have the same methods...

Comment: so you say if i change my if part to use query as the rest of the function it'll be fixed?

Comment: that didn't help either