# Laravel results with Pagination - can I add own variables on trailer information

Tags: laravel, collections, eloquent, pagination

I have a model and use for example like this:

```
$accounts = Account::whereRaw(own criteria)->paginate(3);
```

On $accounts object trailers informattion has:

```
"first_page_url": "https://url_method?page=1",
"from": 1,
"last_page": 3680,
"last_page_url": "https://url_method?page=3680",
"next_page_url": "https://url_method?page=2",
"path": "https://url_method",
"per_page": 3,
"prev_page_url": null,
"to": 3,
"total": 11038
```

I'd like to put below of this information the Request data parameters received. Is it possible? How to?

Comment: How are you returning the response? `return response()->json(compact('accounts'))` like so or similar?

Comment: Do you need something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41034351/add-some-data-in-laravel-paginate ?